# alertify no muestra la ventana y se salta a lasiguiente pagina

Tags: php, alertify

actualmente estoy tratando de utilizar alertify para mejorar la vista de mis alertas. El problema es que con alertify no me muestra la alerta y simplemente cambia de pagina, intente quitando la redireccion de la pagina y ahi si me carga la alerta, pero la redireccion es necesaria, alguna sugerencia?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $serverName = "10.92.184.100";
    $connectionInfo = array ("Database" => "PruebaI", "UID"=>"pablo", "PWD"=>"sdaa",  "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8" );
    $con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $planta=$_POST['planta'];
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios where Usuario = '$usuario' and Password = '$password' and Planta = '$planta'";

    $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta);

    $filas = sqlsrv_rows_affected($resultado);

    if ($filas) {
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Bienvenido Colaborador!");
            window.location.href="CapturaInventario.html"
        </script>';
    }
    else{
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alertify.alert("Datos Incorrectos", function(){
        alertify.message("Confirma tus credenciales");
        window.location.href="Login.html"
        });
        </script>'; 
    }

    sqlsrv_close( $con );


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

debes agregar un evento cuando se presione un boton y luego redirejes,`ajs-button` es la clase de los botones de alertify, asi los identificas y añades el evento.

```
$(".ajs-button").click(function(){window.location="?p='.$url.'";})
```

eso lo tienes que agregar al script

Comment: Estas tratando de dar un respuesta que ni sabes si es cierta o no? ademas el usuario no coloco el formulario de donde viene el resultado, por ende estas lanzando flechas de suerte para ver si ese es, deberias ver la documentacion de alertify antes de decir "creo que era"

Comment: eso estoy haciendo ahora